# How to return windows scheduled task list with php

Tags: php, windows, scheduled-tasks

I need a what for PHP to return all of Windows' (XP) Scheduled Tasks - is this possible?  I'm creating a scheduling script and the user needs to be able to view what time slots are already occupied.

Comment: PHP cannot communicate with the task scheduler on a client machine without the addition of browser plugins.

Comment: is PHP running on the same machine where you wish to view the scheduled tasks?

Comment: I don't want it to perform this client side. @J.J - yeah it's the same machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks promising http://codesnob.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/displaying-windows-task-scheduler-tasks-with-php/

Also, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383448%28VS.85%29.aspx

And finally, http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

**EDIT**

I just ran a test my self and this worked. 32-bit Windows, Zend Server

```
$com = new com("Schedule.Service");
$com->Connect();
$oFolder = $com->GetFolder("\\");
$oCollection = $oFolder->GetTasks(0);
print "Count: " . $oCollection->Count . "n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $oCollection->Count; $i++)
{
      echo $oCollection ->Item($i)->Name ;
}
```

Comment: I actually found a way of doing this with the command line and I'm using php to execute the commands, but I'll give this a shot, thanks.  I'm going to leave the question unanswered for now to see if anyone else has more suggestions.